# Topology just idles on Storm in remote mode

Tags: apache-storm, stormcrawler

I have a Stormcrawler topology (slightly modified from generated one) that will work fine for those 30s in local mode, but when I add `--remote` and submit it, it is registered with Storm, but simply idles around without any values emitted or transferred.

I've had things like this before, but nothing much can be found in the logs to indicate what the problem is (there are more logs than I can read though).

Has anyone seen this before?

Chris

Update:
Ok, found this in the `worker.log`:

2019-07-06 17:04:40.531 STDERR Thread-0 [INFO] Unrecognized VM option 'PrintGCDateStamps'

2019-07-06 17:04:40.531 STDERR Thread-1 [INFO] [0.000s][warning][gc] -Xloggc is deprecated. Will use
-Xlog:gc:artifacts/gc.log instead.

2019-07-06 17:04:40.534 STDERR Thread-0 [INFO] Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.

2019-07-06 17:04:40.535 STDERR Thread-0 [INFO] Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

My guess is that I'm using too new a Java version (11.0.3)?
So I could just remove those JVM opts?

Comment: which versions of StormCrawler and Storm are you on?

Comment: does your topology use the MemorySpout? the stats on the UI are a sample, if there are very few URLs processed it probably won't show. Do the logs show any activity at all?

Comment: I'm using Storm 1.2.2 and StormCrawler 1.14.
I have my own custom spout which reads quite a few urls from a file...
I'm not sure which log location is most relevant, as there are quite a few files being written to.

Comment: I get log entries like (in nimbus.log):
> pool-14-thread-44 [INFO] Activating crawler: crawler-1-1562425476

Otherwise as I said, a lot of noise...

Comment: Ok, for future reference: removing those GC logging options from the worker JVM fixed the problem.

Comment: hi @chris-l the logs for the topologies when running remotely are usually under log/storm/workers-artifacts.
Glad you fixed your problem

Answer (score 3):

I encountered a similar error in my worker log.
The error said `failed to create java virtual machine`:

It turns out that default options for JVM on worker nodes are outdated. Here are default options:

```
worker.childopts: "-Xmx%HEAP-MEM%m -XX:+PrintGCDetails -Xloggc:artifacts/gc.log -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=10 -XX:GCLogFileSize=1M -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=artifacts/heapdump"
```

I removed GC options by overriding in `storm.yaml` file

```
worker.heap.memory.mb: 768 worker.childopts: "-Xmx%HEAP-MEM%m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=artifacts/heapdump" worker.gc.childopts: ""
```

After this update, I restarted storm nodes. The error `cannot start java virtual machine` went away. All my spouts and bolts were able to process the data